# How would you punctuate this?

Tags: modifiers

I've come across a heading I don't know how to punctuate:

10 Questions for Betty Smith – Author, Chocolate and Money Lover

Obviously she is a lover of chocolate and money, but am not sure how/whether to use commas or hyphens here. Any ideas?

Comment: Since what follows her name is an appositive, I would use a comma in the usual way—but rephrase it in order to accommodate that. *10 Questions for Betty Smith, Author and Lover of Chocolate and Money.* However, there is no right answer to this; there will be a lot of different opinions.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't even sure what to google for the list after her name. 'Appositive' it is ;)

Answer (score -1):

My rule on this is to pick one and then stick to it. In a situation with multiple authors, say an office, it usually means a short but intense discussion about choices, then a compromise. The biggest thing is to not switch back and forth, especially in a single document.

My preference for this would be to slightly rewrite, say along the lines of one of these, the choice depending on the tone I was trying to set.

10 Questions for Betty Smith – Author, Lover of Chocolate and Money
10 Questions for Betty Smith – Avaricious Author, Chocolate Lover
10 Questions for Author Betty Smith

Comment: Not clear how this is an answer to the question. Maybe that is why someone downvoted this answer.